# memcpy copies array object to character pointer in C but not vice versa

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, memcpy

I am attempting to copy a character from an array to a character pointer by means of a function. Following is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void pass(void* arg){
    char arr[1];
    arr[0]='X';
    memcpy((char *)arg,arr,1);
}

void main(){
    char *buf=malloc(sizeof(char));
    pass(buf);
    printf("%c",buf);
    free(buf);
}
```

Here, the pointer *buf* prints a garbage value. I tried the reverse of the above program as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void pass(void* arg){
    char arr[1];
    memcpy(arr,(char *)arg,1);
    printf("%c",arr[0]);
}

void main(){
    char *buf=malloc(sizeof(char));
    buf[0]='X';
    pass(buf);
    free(buf);
}
```

This was successful and *arr[0]* prints the value as X.
Could someone clarify why does the first case fail?

Comment: Turn your warnings knob up a notch.

Answer (score 3):

You have to print `*buf` or `buf[0]` instead of `buf` to print the first element of the array pointed by `buf`.

Also note that passing data having type `char*` to be printed via `%c` in `printf()`, which expect data having type `int`, is *undefined behavior* due to type mismatch.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void pass(void* arg){
  char arr[1];
  arr[0]='X';
  memcpy((char *)arg,arr,1);
}
int main(void){
  char *buf=malloc(sizeof(char));
  pass(buf);
  printf("%c",buf[0]);
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here:

```
char *buf=malloc(sizeof(char));
:
printf("%c",buf);
```

because `buf` is a *pointer* to a character, not a character. The *character* is `*buf`, or `buf[0]` so you can fix it with:

```
printf ("%c", *buf);
```

As an aside, it's *totally* unnecessary to create `arr` and call `memcpy` in the first example when you can simply do:

```
void pass (void* arg) {
    ((char*)arg)[0] = 'X';
}
```

Dynamic memory allocation for a character in this case is also unnecessary when you can just replace the `malloc` line with a simple:

```
char buf[1];
```

(and get rid of the `free` line, of course).